# Issues with Importance sampling for flat prior

Tags: bayesian, monte-carlo, t-distribution, importance-sampling, uninformative-prior

I am trying to draw Bayesian inference via importance sampling for a parameter $\xi$ attached with an (unbounded) flat prior. This seems problematic as this is clearly not a probability measure but rather a measure with mass infinity. 
Under a $t$-distributed likelihood with known $\sigma^2 $ and $\nu$ I obtain
$$\log \mathcal{L}(y|\xi)=\frac{-\nu-1}{2}\sum_{t=1}^{T}\log\left(1+\frac{(y_t-\xi)^2}{\nu\sigma^2}\right)$$

> Is this the kernel of a known probability distribution in $\xi_i$?

As I doubt so, I am searching for a importance density that helps me computing sensible weights. 
For example, if I chose $\xi_i \sim N(\mu,\sigma_\xi ^2)$ as importance density, my weights will look like $$w_i=\exp\left(\log\{\mathcal{L}(y|\xi_i)\}+\frac{1}{2\sigma_\xi ^2}(\xi_i-\mu)^2\right).$$ Simulating gives me an extremely high number of weights being equal to $0$.

> How can I overcome this problem?

**Remark: I updated the notation due to a mistake. **

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> **Preliminary:** the issue has nothing to do with using a flat prior. A regular prior would lead to a non-standard posterior all the same.

This model means that you observe $T$ random variates from a $t$ distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom and use a Gaussian as your importance proposal. This makes complete sense as the posterior on $\xi$, while non-standard, is quite close to a Gaussian. While the exact posterior variance of $\xi$ is unknown, it should be close to $s^2/T$, the empirical variance of the data divided by the sample size.
I suggest using $\bar{y}_n$ for $\mu$ and $100 s^2/T$ for $\sigma^2_\xi$ in order to ensure wide enough simulations. *(This can be calibrated by looking at the likelihood values. For instance, use `plot(prop,like(prop))` to observed if the likelihood goes up and then down again. I started with a factor of 4 and this was too small.)*

With such a proposal, here is an R code that runs the said importance sampling experiment, with no visible difficulty:

```
n=35 #your T
T=1e5 #my importance sample size
deg=3 #nu
data=rt(n,df=deg)
like=function(the){
  if (length(the)>1){
   ou=rep(0,length(the))
   for (i in 1:length(the))
    ou[i]=sum(dt(data-the[i],df=deg,log=TRUE))
  }else{
  ou=sum(dt(data-the,df=deg,log=TRUE))}
  return(ou)}
prop=rnorm(T,mean=mean(data),sd=10*sd(data)/n)
iw=like(prop)-dnorm(prop,mean=mean(data),sd=10*sd(data)/n,log=TRUE)
iw=exp(iw-max(iw))
```

For instance, here is the range of the importance weights:

```
> range(iw)
[1] 0.0003463474 1.0000000000
```

And here is the fit between the weighted histogram and the normalised target posterior density.
[image]

Comment: Great, thank you! Can you specify what exactly you calibrated by looking at the likelihood values? If I get it right the parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma_\xi ^2$ are computed to 'fit' the likelihood function. But how to do this?

Comment: If you look at the outcome of `plot(prop,like(prop))` you can check whether you have hit the important zone of the likelihood with your simulations. Or not. And then change $\sigma_\xi$ accordingly.